# node-mysql multiple escaped parameters

Tags: mysql, node.js

As the documentation states, I can use the '?' symbol to automatically replace and escape a parameter.  The following works as expected:

```
dbconn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE iduser = ?', 11, function(err, results) {

        if (err) throw err;
        results[0].Password = '';
        console.log(results);
        res.send(results);
    });
```

But how can I add more parameters?  The following does not work:

```
dbconn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE iduser = ? || iduser = ?', 11, 12, function(err, results) {

        if (err) throw err;
        results[0].Password = '';
        console.log(results);
        res.send(results);
    });
```

Is this possible and can somebody show me the correct syntax to do so?  Thanks

Comment: On a side note (I think the answer below is correct so I'll not bother with that): due to [`pipes_as_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) (which is an `ANSI` thing), I would advise to use the unambigious `OR` instead of `||` for portability.

Comment: @Wrikken Yeah I agree.  I was just using it as an example in this case.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way is to pass an array:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? OR id=?", [3, 4], function(err, results) {...
```

The data in the array is automatically escaped for you.  It's all in the docs

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed / misunderstood.